# Is there any API call or way to read the LinkedIn comment on my self post using REST API?

Tags: linkedin-api

i am using like this for LinkedIn Comment, is there any wrong in call? to read LinkedIn  comments

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?scope=self

but i didn't get the result for comments. i had tried also by passing "after" parameter as a time stamp but still there is no luck ..please  help me to fix this issue

I am looking help from one of you guys

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to include more of the code you're using to make the call?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `oauth2_access_token`
Take a look to:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication